# jQuery nested function keep old data

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have the following piece of code, using jQuery select areas library. I'm trying to modify it to add input label. So if I click on an input, I enable the select areas plugin, retrieve input id and label and then add a new div. It works for the first input, but if I try with a second input, he puts me the first label, in the nested function I didn't have the new value.. :

HTML :

```
<mat-form-field>
    <mat-label>Tesaaaaaaaaat</mat-label>
    <input (focus)="ocr($event)" matInput type="text" id="test">
</mat-form-field>
<mat-form-field>
    <mat-label>bla bla bla</mat-label>
    <input (focus)="ocr($event)" matInput type="text" id="test1">
</mat-form-field>
```

TS :

```
ocr(event: any){
let inputId = event.target.id
let inputLabel = event.target.labels[0].textContent
this.imageInvoice.selectAreas({
    minSize: [20, 20],
    maxSize: [this.imageInvoice.width(), this.imageInvoice.height() / 8],
    onChanged: function(img: any, cpt: any, selection: any) {
        if ($('#select-area-label_' + cpt).length == 0)
            $('#select-areas-label-container_' + cpt).append('<div id="select-area-label_' + cpt + '">' + inputLabel + '</div>')
    }
});
```

}

I tried to move the inputLabel declaration into `onChanged` but same result, inputLabel keep the first used value

Thansk in advance

Comment: Hi, can you make this runnable ?

Comment: I'm trying to, but I'm struggling with jquery :/
https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ivy-psenby?file=angular.json

Comment: Sorry , but i am not able to run that . Please can you fix it ?